# acessing the Sonarqube with http://xyz.abc.com:9000

Tags: java, eclipse, optimization, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

We are working in project where we wanted to customized the rule. To customized the rule, we need to upload a file to sonar server. As we are working in a restricted environment where we can't upload the file to unknown server. We can only upload the file only if server url end with abc.com.

is there any way to change the url 
 `http://localhost:9000 to http://xyz.abc.com:9000`..??

Comment: You've asked two entirely separate questions here. Consider splitting this.

Comment: thanks for the reply, please provide answer to the point 1 atleast

Comment: I have added the property in sonar propeties file sonar.web.host=xyz.abc.com,sonar.web.port=9000 but still i am not able to access the sonar console using http://xyz.abc.com:9000

Answer (score 0):

Your question is completely independent from SonarQube as it boils down to hostname management, mapping *xyz.abc.com* to *localhost* (and/or to SonarQube server's IP). Changing *sonar.web.host* (as per your above comment) won't help at all as it is for SonarQube to bind on a specific interface, something unrelated to your situation here.

Approach your problem from a network connectivity (and name resolution) perspective. Your goal can be summed up in: `xyz.abc.com` must resolve to the IP of the server which hosts SonarQube.

If all work is only done locally for now then per comment from @snakecharmerb you can update your `/etc/hosts` with a new mapping, otherwise update your DNS with a new entry.